# Windows UWP development problems (Windows 10 Emulator and Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have a few problems that are driving me nuts.

I have the latest Windows 10 SDK (10586.212) and Emulator 10586.11. I have seen before (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) that the Emulator for 10586.212 is available too, so I download it.

All good till here. That the problem is when I want to install it it says I must uninstall the previous version 10586.11. Ok, no problem, I do it and re-run the install. And than it shows that it wants to install 10586.11 emulator again. Wtf ?

I was thinking it is just a typo error and press install, but no, it did install 10586.11. How can I get the emulator for 10586.212 ?

And another problem for Xamarin Studio. I installed xamarin tools and I have it in visual studio, but it didn't install xamarin studio ?

Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin Studio for Windows is no longer provided in the installer as we encourage developers to use Visual Studio. If you still require it, we can provide you with the download link if you reach out to contact@xamarin.com

Comment: thanks, I found it later but it still didn't install as I got an error. But I don't need it, I was just thinking why it didn't install. I want to resolve the problem with the newer emulator though:/

Comment: @Skynet - the latest version of the Windows 10 Emulator is 10.0.10586.11. The SDK had to update the number to ship a fix. If you have 10.0.10586.11, you have the latest.

Answer (score -1):

you should have to change settings of Hyper V. then try to install emulator it will working perfect.